# Determine the Zero-State Response and Zero-Input Response

Tags: transfer-function

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHyZ2w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For t > 0 I have determined the transfer function:

$$ \hat{H}(s)=\frac{\hat{Y}(s)}{\hat{F}(s)}= \frac{s}{s^{2}+s+1} $$

Now I need to find the zero-state response for t > 0 if: $$ f(t)=e^{3t} $$

And the zero-input response for t > 0 if: $$ y(0^{-})=1V \ , \ i(0^{-})=0 $$

Are the ZSR and ZIR related to h(t) or would it be i(t)? I know that for ZIR F(s)=0. But what piece of this problem is the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the zero state: Find

$$
F(s) =\frac{1} {(s-3)}
$$

Which is computed by taking the Laplace transform of course.
Now, multiply F(s) with your transfer function.
You will have
$$
Y(s) = \frac{s} { (s-3)(s^2+s+1)}
$$

Now simply, use partial fraction and take Laplace inverse to find y(t)

Solution on wolframalpha:

[Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+Laplace+transform+s%2F%28%28s%5E2%2Bs%2B1%29*%28s-3%29%29)

[image]

As for the zero state response:
You can find the differential equation by doing the cross multiplication
As for s^2 is second derivative and "s" is first derivative:
$$
y' ' + y' + y = f '
$$
Take Laplace transform again considering initial conditions:
$$
s^2Y(s) - sy(0) - y'(0) + sY(s) - y(o) + Y(s) = sF(s) - f(0)
$$
No as for the input F(s) = 0 (for zero input)

So,
$$
Y(s) = \frac{sy(0) + y'(0) +y(0)}{(s^2 +s +1)}
$$
Now sub for the initial conditions and take Laplace inverse to find y(t).